# How to make the call on the server side and keep the functionality

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

So I have been stuck on this feature for a while, I'm trying to implement pagination in a data that is being fetched from a 3rd party API which is constantly changing, the thing about this API is the calls can only be made on the server, client side fetching is not permitted.

So I've figured out how to use SWR hook to update my data constantly but however I'm unable to configure a pagination option, I've managed to make it work on the client side but I cannot get it working on the server side.

This is what my code so far is like, it works on the local host but on production it gives out cors errors and the api calls dont work,

```
const SWRTest = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    `https://exampleapi.co/matches/upcoming?sort=&page=${page}&per_page=30&token=#`,
    fetcher
  );
  console.log(data)
  console.log(page)


  if (error) return <div>Something went wrong...</div>
  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <ul role="list">
      <button

        onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}
      >
        Previous
      </button>

      <button

        onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}
      >
        Next
      </button>
      {data &&
        data.map((game) => (
          <li key={game.id}>{game.name}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default SWRTest
```

Errors -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.co/matches/upcoming?sort=&page=1&per_page=30&token=#' from origin 'https://riffyraff.me' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
     

  GET https://api.example.co/matches/upcoming?sort=&page=1&per_page=30&token=# net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

I think the API call is being blocked cause its being made on the client side which is not allowed by the API provider.

Comment: Also, add the actual log of the error you're receiving

Comment: My bad, Just did that

Comment: Have you tried making the request to the third-party API from an API route, then make the request to the API route from the client-side (using the API route as proxy, essentially)?

Comment: Yes that will work, I have tried that but I'm not sure how I could manipulate that API route? So for example my route is called `games`, how can I possibly pass the `{page}` into that?